# search result page showing error while trying to show current category and child category in sidebar of magento

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, catalogsearch

I used the following code

```
   <?php 
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$children = Mage::registry( 'current_category' )->getChildrenCategories(); 
$parent = Mage::registry( 'current_category' );  ?> 
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($parent); ?>"><?php echo $parent->getName() ?></a>
    </li>     
    <?php foreach( $children as $child ): ?>       
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($child); ?>"><?php echo $child->getName() ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

to show c`urrent category and child category on each page it working well` but when i `search any term in the search box then it will show product but in sidebar` it will show fatal error. so any one can suggest me the solution of this problem any help will be important for me.

Answer (score 3):

Magento `only set current_category registry variable` for  Category page and it `donot set on` catalog search page. So  you got this error.

So ,`put some logic like current page is category page check` it works.

**logic is like**

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName()=='catalog') {
// then you code is works
}
```